# jQuery UI Slider for changing Image with auto slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I´d like to build a UI Slider to change an Image. So far, I´ve managed that the Image will change manually and automaticly every three Seconds.
I´m not very happy with the code, because when it reaches the max-value and repeats from beginning, it skippes the last value because of the setInterval. Is there an easier and prettier way to solve this?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="image" src="http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=0&font=lobster" />
    </div>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    $('#slider').slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        step: 1,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            var slideruivalue = (ui.value);
            image = $('#image');
            image.attr('src', 'http://fakeimg.pl/350x200/?text=' + slideruivalue);

            if (slideruivalue == $(this).data("slider").options.max) {
                $('#slider').slider('value', 0);
            }
        }
    });

    $(function AutoSlider() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#slider").slider("value", $('#slider').slider("value") + 1);
        }, 3000);
        setTimeout(AutoSlider, 3000);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dawall/q5R68/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setTimeout, get the max of your slider, and then calculate the new value with a modulus (operator %) on max+1 :

```
    setInterval(function () {
        var value = $('#slider').slider("value");
        var max = $('#slider').slider( "option", "max" );
        $("#slider").slider("value", (value + 1)% (max+1));
    }, 3000);
```

Then, there is no need to check the value in the change callback :)

You can also use setInterval instead of two setTimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/q5R68/1/